# Find() takes no keyword arguments @ web scraping

Tags: webscarab

please help me find the error as i didn’t understand `for` correctly :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250'
response = requests.get(url)
with open("imdb_top_250_movies.html", mode='wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
df_list = []
for movie in soup:
    title = movie.find('td' , class_="titleColumn").find('a').contents[0]
    year = movie.find('td' , class_="titleColumn").find('span').contents[0][1:-1]
    user_rating = movie.find('td' , class_="ratingColumn imdbRating").find('strong').contents[0]
    df_list.append({'title': title,
                    'year': int(year),
                    'user_ratings': float(user_rating)})
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns = ['title', 'year', 'user_ratings'])
df
```

This is the error I got

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [125], in <cell line: 8>()
> 9 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
> 10 df_list = []
> ---> 11 title = movie.find('td' , class_="titleColumn").find('a').contents[0]
> 12 year = soup.find('td' , class_="titleColumn").find('span').contents[0][1:-1]
> 13 user_rating = soup.find('td' , class_="ratingColumn imdbRating").find('strong').contents[0]
>
> TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me with this answer as I wrote `For` incorrectly :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/chart/top'
response = requests.get(url)
with open("imdb_top_250_movies.html", mode='wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
df_list = []
for movie in soup.find('tbody' , class_="lister-list").find_all('tr'):
    Place = movie.find('td' , class_="titleColumn").contents[0][1:-len('.\n      ')]
    title = movie.find('td' , class_="titleColumn").find('a').contents[0]
    year = movie.find('td' , class_="titleColumn").find('span').contents[0][1:-1]
    user_rating = movie.find('td' , class_="ratingColumn imdbRating").find('strong').contents[0]
    df_list.append({'place': Place,
                    'title': title,
                    'year': int(year),
                    'user_ratings': float(user_rating)})
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns = ['place','title', 'year', 'user_ratings'])
df.style.hide(axis='index')
```